# Re-order column fields with ajax drag and drop functionality? PHP/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

At the moment I'm building a site and one of the features is the ability to create a list and you can then add links to a specific list. A list will have many links.

I want to order the list of links by `weight` by simply dragging and dropping `li` elements into a new position and then updating the database with the links `weight` via an ajax call.

Lists table: `id | list_title | list_description | user_id | rating | views | date_created`

Links table: `id | title | url | user_id | list_id | weight | date_created`

view file

```
<ul id="links_list">
<?php

if($links->num_rows() >= 1){

    $i = 0;

    foreach($links->result_array() as $link){

        echo "<li class=\"list_item-".$i."\">";
        echo ''.$link['title'].'<br><br>';
        echo "</li>";

        $i++;
    }

}else{

    echo "You have not yet added any links to this list.";

}

?>
</ul>
```

I know this isn't much to go on but unsure how to accomplish this or where to even start.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: jquery ui [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/). I've done this by putting hidden input elements in the li's with names like `sort[]` and adding a "save" button at the bottom. They come through the form in the sorted order.

Comment: @IvanButtinoni In what way does it seem that I'm asking someone to write the code for me? I'm simply asking what the process would be to get something like this up and running.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I see where your coming from. I'm assuming that I would be able to do this without the save button though as I'm wanting to make the order update automatically?

Comment: Check out the API documentation. There are events like `change` that you could fire off an ajax request to send the data to a server.

Comment: @IvanButtinoni Why even comment? Waste of time. There is no good answer because their is not many people attempting to help me. So arrogant!!!

Comment: @IvanButtinoni If your comment is not constructive to the question or problem, then you probably shouldn't comment. If you feel a question is not a good one, then vote. Vote it down, vote to close and be on your way. If it really is a bad question, it will get closed. Little quips like this that offer no help are what make SO a hard place for new programmers to enjoy.

Comment: I added my suggestion as an answer because you will want to close the question (accept an answer) eventually.

Comment: First of all I try to help people, even my first (bit acid) comment was an help and it did helped: the question is poor but the answer is great!

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, I wan't be unpleasant, but point out that a question is a *bit* insubstantial is the first step to understand the "real question". May be my comment is a *bit* too critic :D
I like SO too and your policy and your answer, in fact I was opening jQueryUi when you made your "sort" comment, you're very quick! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up coming up with my solution to this problem which is the following.

view

```
<ul id="links_list" class="sortable">
<?php

if($links->num_rows() >= 1){

    $i = 0;

    foreach($links->result_array() as $link){

        echo "<li id=\"list_item-".$link['id']."\">";
        echo ''.$link['title'].'<br><br>';
        echo "</li>";

        $i++;
    }

}else{

    echo "You have not yet added any links to this list.";

}

?>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$("#links_list").sortable(
{
    connectWith: '.sortable',    
    update : function () 
    { 
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url + "links/reorder",
            data: 
            {
                links: $("#links_list").sortable('serialize')              
            },
            success: function(html)
            {
                html;
            }
        });
    } 

}).disableSelection();
```

links/reorder php script

```
public function reorder(){

    parse_str($this->input->post('links'), $links); 

    foreach($links['list_item'] as $key => $value){

        $this->db->set('weight', $key);
        $this->db->where('id', $value);
        $this->db->update('links');

    }

}
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [jquery ui sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/). You can attach to one of the events like `change` to get the list as changes are made and send off an ajax call to the server for saving